# Why do the results vary for generator output when using list or a for loop

Tags: python, string, generator

**Behaviour 1**

code with join:

```
print (' '.join(str(list(random.randrange(100) for j in range(4)))))
```

output:

```
[ 8 2 ,   8 3 ,   1 2 ,   7 1 ]
```

What I expected was:

```
[82,83,12,71]
```

Observation:

I'm using the list() function as I need to evaluate the generator expression. I assume this is where I'm going wrong, should I not be using list() with generators?

**Behaviour 2:**

code: same code ( without list()) but wrapped around another for loop:

```
for _ in range(2**2):
    print (' '.join(str(random.randrange(100)) for i in range(4)))
```

output:

```
98 72 56 63
71 12 45 63
83 91 65 89
31 45 65 95
```

Observation:

Here I get the expected out put. But I don't understand why this would work vs Behaviour 1 with a list.
My understanding was that both a for loop and a list can be used interchangeably to force the output from a generator. What am I missing in understanding the difference where str() is taking the whole number in behaviour 2 but treating the output as a sequence of characters for behaviour 1?

Comment: Code #1 does not produce output #1 (code is joining the underscore character, which does not appear in your output).

Comment: Good spot, I edited it to show the problem better then forgot to re-run it. I've taken the underscore out. Thanks

Comment: "I'm using the list() function as I need to evaluate the generator expression. " **that doesn't make any sense**. You use `list` *if you want to create a list*, in this case, you don't.

Comment: What you are missing is **the argument you are passing to `' '.join`, in the first case, it is a `str`, created by `str(list(random.randrange(100) for j in range(4)))`, which is a string representation of a list that will look like: `'[70, 63, 55, 72]'`, hence, `' '.join` will seperate *every item in the iterable* by the space. Iterating over a string iterates over the characters. In the second case, you pass `str(random.randrange(100)) for i in range(4))` which is a generator which will yield individual strings. Those strings will be seperated by a space by `join`

Comment: Thank you this was brilliant explanation. Very clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code #1 is joining the string representation of a list, placing a space between each character in that string representation.  Code 2 is joining a list of string representations, separating each with a space.